# Access Class Instance from Function Scope

Tags: python

Why can't set_a access the attributes of the MyClass instance but set_b can?

```
NameError: global name 'my_instance' is not defined
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class MyClass(object):
        a = 1
        b = 2

def set_a():
        my_instance.a = 5
        my_instance.b = 6

def main():
    def set_b():
            my_instance.a = 3
            my_instance.b = 4

    my_instance = MyClass()
    print my_instance.a, my_instance.b
    set_b()
    print my_instance.a, my_instance.b
    set_a()
    print my_instance.a, my_instance.b

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your instances as parameters:

```
def set_a(my_a):
        my_a.a = 5
        my_a.b = 6

def main():
    def set_b(my_a):
            my_a.a = 3
            my_a.b = 4

    my_instance = MyClass()
    print my_instance.a, my_instance.b
    set_b(my_instance)
    print my_instance.a, my_instance.b
    set_a(my_instance)
    print my_instance.a, my_instance.b

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `set_a` doesn't see `my_instance` because it is defined in different scope. If it would be defined outside main then it should work:

```
my_instance = None
...
def set_a(): ...
...
def main(): ...
```

Though I would suggest to pass `my_instance` as a parameter instead of defining as global variable.